# Using Karate Feature tests to generate code coverage for a multi module maven project that sonar can read

Tags: spring, maven, sonarqube, karate, jacoco

I have a mutli module maven spring project that has limited unit tests but we need to show code coverage ^80% in sonar.

We have Karate Feature and integration tests can either be used to generate coverage that sonar can read.

Would Karate junit be a possible solution

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#code-coverage-using-jacoco

tried this locally but did not get too far would this be the right track

Comment: code coverage is hard and whatever information is available has been collected in the link you posted, code and contributions are welcome

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.